# Trying to subscribe to table changes via supabasejs -- subscribe is working, but no changes detected

Tags: supabase

I am trying to subscribe to table changes in supabase via the supabasejs library, like so:

```
const sb = supabase.createClient(projurl, apiKey);
sb
    .channel('any')
    .on('postgres_changes', { event: '*', schema: '*', table:'SomeTable', filter:'id=eq.'+i}, payload => {
      console.log('Change received for row:' + i, payload)
    })
    .subscribe()
```

The subscription is working, but no changes are detected, do I need to do anything on the supabase side of things?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to do three things in order for the subscription on() event to fire in your client:

1. In Supabase > Database > Replication, be sure the table has replication on.
2. In Supabase > Database > Tables, edit your table and be sure 'Enable Realtime' is checked.
3. In Supabase > Authentication > Policies, create at least a read policy for your table.

I hope that works for you, haha! :)